# How do I create a rule with CloudFormation that calls a Gateway API every few minutes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

I'm trying to create a CloudWatch rule in CloudFormation that triggers one of our Gateway APIs every few minutes and I'm having trouble finding documentation on how to fill certain parts of the template.

For example, this is what we have in our CF template:

```
SomeAPI:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: api
      Runtime: go1.x
      CodeUri: ../../deploy/bla.zip
      Timeout: 600
      VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
        - !ImportValue VPCSecurityGroup
        SubnetIds:
        - !ImportValue PrivateSubnetA
        - !ImportValue PrivateSubnetB

      Events:
        TestApiPing:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /test-api/ping
            Method: GET
```

I would like to have CF create a rule that calls the ping API, but am having difficulty filling in the targets section:

```
TestRule:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      Name: "test-ping-rule"
      ScheduleExpression: "cron(0/15 * ? * * *)"
      Targets:
        -
          Arn:
            Fn::GetAtt:
              - "PingFunction"
              - <what to put here?>
            Id: "TargetFunctionV1"
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why would you schedule a call for API Gateway instead of scheduling a Lambda function execution?

Comment: I don't have to, but our Lambda functions were defined like this using AWS::Serverless::Function. I don't know how to reference the Lambda functions in this way.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to figure out the solution after much trial and error today. Under the Events section of the serverless function definition, you can do this:

```
Events:
        PublicApi:
          Type: Schedule
          Properties:
            Schedule: cron(0/5 * ? * * *)
            Input: '{ "httpMethod": "GET", "path": "/public_api/ping" }'
```